# GetAdaptersAddresses() not giving correct IP address

Tags: c++, c, sockets, visual-c++, network-programming

I am using a USB Internet dongle that assigns an IPv6 address to my computer. When I use `ipconfig`, I can see the IPv6 address assigned, it's a public IP.

When I use [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx), I get a long linked list of anycast, multicast, and unicast addresses, but none of them match the system's IP address.

Is there some other place where I would get system's IP?  I actually want to get the IP address of the system so that I can bind it to a socket.

I use Windows 7.

```
// getadaptersinfo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<iphlpapi.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include<iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"IPHLPAPI.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\nusing getadapteraddress";
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES p, tp;
    ULONG u;
    DWORD ret;
    p = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES));
    u = sizeof(p);
    GetAdaptersAddresses(0, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, p, &u);
    p = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, u);
    ret = GetAdaptersAddresses(0, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, p, &u);
    if (ret == NO_ERROR)
    {
        tp = p;
        while (tp)
        {
            cout << "\nlength of ip adapter address";
            tp->Length;
            cout << "\nifindex (ipv4):" << tp->IfIndex;
            cout << "\n Adapter name::" << tp->AdapterName;
            PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pu;
            pu = tp->FirstUnicastAddress;
            int i = 0;
            cout << "\nunicast address:";
            while (pu)
            {
                i++;
                cout << "\nlength of sockaddr: " << (pu->Address).iSockaddrLength;
                if (pu->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv4 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                else if (pu->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv6 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                pu = pu->Next;
            }
            cout << "\n no of unicast address" << i;
            PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS pa;
            i = 0;
            pa = tp->FirstAnycastAddress;
            cout << "\nanycast address:"; 
            while (pa)
            {
                i++;
                cout << "\nlength of sockaddr: " << (pa->Address).iSockaddrLength;
                if (pa->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv4 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pa->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                else if (pa->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv6 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pa->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                pa = pa->Next;
            }
            cout << "\n no of anycast address" << i;
            PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS pm;
            i = 0;
            pm = tp->FirstMulticastAddress;
            cout << "\nmulticast address:";
            while (pm)
            {
                i++;
                cout << "\nlength of sockaddr: " << (pm->Address).iSockaddrLength;
                if (pm->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv4 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pm->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                else if (pm->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv6 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pm->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                pm = pm->Next;
            }
            cout << "\n no of multicast address" << i;
            PIP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS pd;
            i = 0;
            pd = tp->FirstDnsServerAddress;
            cout << "\ndns address:";
            while (pd)
            {
                i++;
                cout << "\nlength of sockaddr: " << (pd->Address).iSockaddrLength;
                if (pd->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv4 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pd->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                else if (pd->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv6 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pd->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                pd = pd->Next;
            }
            cout << "\n no of dns server address" << i;
            PIP_ADAPTER_GATEWAY_ADDRESS_LH pg;
            i = 0;
            pg = tp->FirstGatewayAddress;
            cout << "\ngateway address:"; 
            while (pg)
            {
                i++;
                cout << "\nlength of sockaddr: " << (pg->Address).iSockaddrLength;
                if (pg->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv4 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pg->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                else if (pg->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    cout << "\n ipv6 addr:";
                    sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pg->Address.lpSockaddr);
                    char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si, a, sizeof(a));
                    cout << a;
                }
                pg = pg->Next;
            }
            cout << "\ngateway address:" << i;
            cout << "\n dns suffix" << tp->DnsSuffix;
            cout << "\n description" << tp->Description;
            cout << "\n friendly name" << tp->FriendlyName;
            if (tp->PhysicalAddressLength != 0)
                for (UINT i = 0; i < tp->PhysicalAddressLength; i++)
                {
                    if (i == (tp->PhysicalAddressLength - 1))
                        cout << std::hex << (int)tp->PhysicalAddress[i];
                    else
                        cout << "-" << std::hex << (int)tp->PhysicalAddress[i];
                }
            cout << "\n Flags" << tp->Flags;
            cout << "\nmtu" << tp->Mtu;
            cout << "\n IfType" << tp->IfType;
            cout << "\n OperStatus" << tp->OperStatus;
            cout << "\n ipv6 ifindex :" << tp->Ipv6IfIndex;
            cout << "\nand more";
            tp = tp->Next;
        }

    }
    else {
        cout << "something went wrong";
    }
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
    p = NULL;
    cin >> ret;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, none of the addresses match the address in the command prompt.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: First, `GetAdaptersAddresses()` is not part of WinSock, it is part of the IP Helper API.  Second, it works fine, so you must not be using it correctly.  Please show your actual code.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau   changes made. Code in the link with images. Please look.

Comment: @FookieRookie: "*Code in the link with images. Please look*" - It is against StackOverflow policies to host code and images on an external site. If you can't be bothered to show your code on this system, people here can't be bothered to go look at it on someone else's system. This is a Q&A site. Questions should be self-contained. External links break over time.  I have corrected your mistake this time. Please don't make it again next time.

Comment: Understood. I need to have rank 10 to post a picture and as I am new here so did this

Comment: Please help me with this!!

Answer (score 5):

I see a number of problems with your code:

- you are not performing adequate error handling when calling `GetAdaptersAddresses()`.
- you are leaking the first `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` struct that you allocate.
- you are not outputting `tp->Length` to the console at the top of your `while (tp)` loop.
- you are not retrieving and formatting the IP addresses correctly!

That last point is the root of your problem.

When you attempt to retrieve an IP address from the list, you are accessing the `sockaddr_X` struct incorrectly.

This code:

```
sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);

sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
```

Needs to be like this instead:

```
sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);

sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
```

The `lpSockaddr` field is *already* a pointer to a `sockaddr_X` struct, so you need to type-cast that pointer value, DO NOT use the `&` operator to take the address of that pointer itself, you would be type-casting the wrong memory address and so the binary data you attempt to format for the IP address is garbage!

You are also calling `inet_ntop()` incorrectly.  It expects a pointer to a  `in_addr`/`in6_addr` struct as input, but you are passing it a pointer to a `sockaddr_in`/`sockaddr_in6` struct instead.  So the formatted output strings are garbage as well!

This code:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, si, a, sizeof(a));

inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si, a, sizeof(a));
```

Needs to be like this instead:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(si->sin_addr), a, sizeof(a));

inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(si->sin6_addr), a, sizeof(a));
```

You are making these 2 mistakes for all of the anycast, unicast, multicast, DNS server, and gateway IP addresses in the linked lists.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
// getadaptersinfo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"IPHLPAPI.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void displayAddress(const SOCKET_ADDRESS &Address)
{
    cout << "\n  Length of sockaddr: " << Address.iSockaddrLength;
    if (Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
    {
        sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)(Address.lpSockaddr);
        char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(si->sin_addr), a, sizeof(a)))
            cout << "\n   IPv4 address: " << a;
    }
    else if (Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
    {
        sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)(Address.lpSockaddr);
        char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(si->sin6_addr), a, sizeof(a)))
            cout << "\n   IPv6 address: " << a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "\nUsing GetAdaptersAddresses";

    ULONG size = 1024 * 15;    
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES p = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size);
    if (!p)
    {
        cout << "\nCannot allocate memory";
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    ULONG ret;
    do
    {
        ret = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, p, &size);
        if (ret != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
            break;

        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES newp = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*) HeapReAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p, size);
        if (!newp)
        {
            cout << "\nCannot reallocate memory";
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
            cin.get();
            return -1;
        }

        p = newp;
    }
    while (true);

    if (ret != NO_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "\nSomething went wrong. Error: " << ret;
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for(PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES tp = p; tp != NULL; tp = tp->Next)
    {
        ++i;
        cout << "\nLength of IP Adapter info: " << tp->Length;
        cout << "\n IPv4 IfIndex: " << tp->IfIndex;
        cout << "\n Adapter name: " << tp->AdapterName;
        cout << "\n Unicast addresses:";
        int j = 0;
        for (PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pu = tp->FirstUnicastAddress; pu != NULL; pu = pu->Next)
        {
            ++j;
            displayAddress(pu->Address);
        }
        cout << "\n # of Unicast addresses: " << j;
        cout << "\n Anycast addresses:"; 
        j = 0;
        for (PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS pa = tp->FirstAnycastAddress; pa != NULL; pa = pa->Next)
        {
            ++j;
            displayAddress(pa->Address);
        }
        cout << "\n # of Anycast addresses: " << j;
        cout << "\n Multicast addresses:";
        j = 0;
        for (PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS pm = tp->FirstMulticastAddress; pm != NULL; pm = pm->Next)
        {
            ++j;
            displayAddress(pm->Address);
        }
        cout << "\n # of Multicast addresses: " << j;
        cout << "\n DNS server addresses:";
        j = 0;
        for (PIP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS pd tp->FirstDnsServerAddress; pd != NULL; pd = pd->Next)
        {
            ++j;
            displayAddress(pd->Address);
        }
        cout << "\n # of DNS server addresses: " << j;
        cout << "\n Gateway addresses:"; 
        j = 0;
        for (PIP_ADAPTER_GATEWAY_ADDRESS_LH pg = tp->FirstGatewayAddress; pg != NULL; pg = pg->Next)
        {
            ++j;
            displayAddress(pg->Address);
        }
        cout << "\n # of Gateway addresses: " << j;
        cout << "\n DNS suffix" << tp->DnsSuffix;
        cout << "\n Description" << tp->Description;
        cout << "\n Friendly name" << tp->FriendlyName;
        if (tp->PhysicalAddressLength != 0)
        {
            cout << "\n Physical address: ";
            cout << std::hex << (int)tp->PhysicalAddress[0];
            for (UINT i = 1; i < tp->PhysicalAddressLength; i++)
                cout << "-" << std::hex << (int)tp->PhysicalAddress[i];
        }
        cout << "\n Flags" << tp->Flags;
        cout << "\n MTU" << tp->Mtu;
        cout << "\n IfType" << tp->IfType;
        cout << "\n OperStatus" << tp->OperStatus;
        cout << "\n IPv6 IfIndex :" << tp->Ipv6IfIndex;
        cout << "\n and more...";
    }
    cout << "\n# of IP Adapters: " << i;

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: else
                    cout << "-" << std::hex << (int)tp->PhysicalAddress[i]; should be   cout << std::hex << (int)tp->PhysicalAddress[i]  << "-" ;

Comment: @user3461121 I have rewritten that loop to use a different approach.

Answer (score -2):

This code:

```
sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)&(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)&(pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
```

Needs to be like this instead:

```
sockaddr_in *si = ((sockaddr_in *)pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
sockaddr_in6 *si = ((sockaddr_in6 *)pu->Address.lpSockaddr);
```

Comment: The other answer already explains this I think.

Comment: The reasoning of your subtly different application of operators is non-obvious. Please explain the functional difference of your code proposal, in comparison to the passage from the other existing answer which seems (but actually is not) a 100% letter by letter copy. You will have to do some explaining to avoid the impression of having copied from an upvoted answer for unappreciated reasons.