# Is there another function, besides GetNetworkParams, to help me find the IPs of the DNS servers from my machine?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dns

I want to find out the ip addresses of the local dns servers using another function besides GetNetworkParams. (in C language)

Comment: Add more context about what you are trying to accomplish. Why do you not want to use the correct API? Which language, etc?

Comment: [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) can get you the DNS servers assigned to each network adapter on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Remy said, you can use [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses).

This is an example implemented in C language:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"IPHLPAPI.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

void displayAddress(const SOCKET_ADDRESS Address)
{
    if (Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in* si = (struct sockaddr_in*)(Address.lpSockaddr);
        char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(si->sin_addr), a, sizeof(a)))
            printf("\n   IPv4 address: %s", a);
    }
    else if (Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6* si = (struct sockaddr_in6*)(Address.lpSockaddr);
        char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(si->sin6_addr), a, sizeof(a)))
            printf("\n   IPv6 address: %s", a);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ULONG size = 1024 * 15;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES p = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size);
    if (!p)
    {
        printf("\nCannot allocate memory");
        return -1;
    }

    ULONG ret;
    do
    {
        ret = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, p, &size);
        if (ret != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
            break;

        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES newp = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*)HeapReAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p, size);
        if (!newp)
        {
            printf("\nCannot reallocate memory");
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
            return -1;
        }

        p = newp;
    } while (1);

    if (ret != NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nSomething went wrong. Error: %d", ret);
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
        return -1;
    }

    for (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES tp = p; tp != NULL; tp = tp->Next)
    {
        printf("\n DNS server addresses:");
        for (PIP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS pd = tp->FirstDnsServerAddress; pd != NULL; pd = pd->Next)
        {
            displayAddress(pd->Address);
        }
    }
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
    return 0;
}
```

More reference: [GetAdaptersAddresses() not giving correct IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802023/13566062)

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.